# Help Desk Suite (or combo of software) - free/open source if possible

Tags: help-desk

I am assisting a friend in revamping their help desk ticketing system, documentation system, and more right now. Currently they use a lot of Word Docs and notepad documents all semi-organized on a network drive. As well, when they get tickets in, they don't even use a ticketing system, they just email each other. So with that being said, anything would be a step up for them right now. :)

So here are the reqs they are looking for in the suite/system that they want to implement.

1. Centralized ticketing system
2. Knowledge Base
3. Email notifications (both manual and automated)
4. Web interface
5. Software can be locally installed or local/web to give multiple I/O for employees and clients
6. Project management system
7. Reporting of anything and everything possible
8. LDAP integration

Now, there are a few things that they have said would be nice to have and good bonuses

1. Checklist piece to the tickets/projects. This means that the Help Desk employee would put on there all of the things the client is requesting. Then, as they are completed they can be "checked off" to show completion.
2. The client can log on to a web portal and see any and all status updates. Giving clear visibility to their requests.
3. Mobile app option, specifically something like Base camp and how their project management can be done.
4. The website would need to be more designed like an interface than a core designed page. This would allow the customization of the page to how they want it.
5. Tickets can be updated if a client were to reply to an email and it had a unique number in the subject that would put that email and/or the attachments in to the ticketing system.
6. The knowledge base can be both private and public. So the things that clients can fix themselves would be public and viewable on the website. Otherwise, they would be private for employee use only.

Lastly, this all needs to be done and used on Windows OS and servers.

Now, I do understand how much is above and I know that not one software/suite will have everything...especially being free or open source. However, if there are say...2 options that would give almost all of the items above, then that wouldn't be so bad. The ABSOLUTE most they would want to do is 3 software, but that use pushing it.

Again, this needs to be free out open source as they are a smaller company. They have investigated paying for all the items they wanted with multiple companies, but the costs were going to be astronomical and they wouldn't get a return on their investment for many years.

Thanks for all of the feedback and help. Definitely looking forward to hearing any and all feed back.

Comment: trying looking on https://sourceforge.net/

Comment: Wah!  You are a Mapler !  Yay!!     Now I feel hon(u)r bound to help you F2

Comment: Related and worth a look (one of the answers might even fit): [Help Desk Software?](/q/1613/185) / [Helpdesk / Customer Relationship Management (CRM) software](/q/10309/185) // our other [answered helpdesk questions](/search?q=helpdesk+answers%3A1). The modular, Python based management suite *Trac* (see [these answers](/search?q=trac+is%3Aanswer) might be a good fit as well.

Comment: Thank you for all of these recommendations. I will definitely have to sort through them and see what I can find that will work. Right now they have been contemplating building their own from scratch as they have a lot of programmers in their company and can do a lot of things. However, they don't want to waste their time programming something that they might be available out there already for them to manipulate.

Comment: Oh, and I am a Mapler. I haven't played for a long time, but I do still have my accounts and enjoy logging on from time to time. It is truly crazy how much the game has changed. I remember when they added the underwater zone and when Ludi was even a thing yet. Man, those were the times. Lol

Comment: I had 9  years on MApleSEA, then a few on Europe, before they combined it go global. Almost made my first char to level 200 & they moved the goalpoasts, so now I am grinding towards 250 F2

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it is too long to post as a comment.

I have to help you before the Wyvern get you (or is it Skelegon?)

[image]

**Must have**

1. Centralized ticketing system
2. Knowledge Base
3. Email notifications (both manual and automated)
4. Web interface
5. Software can be locally installed or local/web to give multiple I/O for employees and clients
6. Project management system
7. Reporting of anything and everything possible
8. LDAP integration

Numbers 1, 3, 4, 5 and probably 6 & 7 can be provided by any [issue tracking system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system) such as those used for software development, so Google for those and look at [past question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=issue+tracking) on the subject on this site.

I am not sure how [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) fits in, but would imagine that the big players in issue management have it covered.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems) might help you to choose an Issue Tracking System.

I think that most will also cover you second list of "nice to have"s.

Alternatively, you could try some of the more modern, cloud-based, collaboration solutions, like [Asana](https://asana.com/), etc (there are many, but that's the only one that I know).

During one decade of [Maple Story](http://maplestory.nexon.net/landing/) and several decades of professional software development, I have found the industry standards to be [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/) for a FOSS solution and [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) to be the paid solution of choice, with [pricing](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/pricing) or $10/user/month for up to 10 users, and $7 for up to 100 users, which further price drops thereafter.

Really, I think that all you have to do is to choose a free or paid Issue Tracker, and then think about adding a knowledge [base](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all-your-base-are-belong-to-us), and whether that should be standalone, or if it *must* be integrated into the issue tracker.

The "comparison of issue trackers" Wikipedia page which I linked above indicates that several have built in knowledge bases, so I would suggest wading through those and evaluating them.

[This page](https://www.capterra.com/issue-tracking-software/) might also be useful, as it lets you check desired features and show you which Issue Trackers would help - however, I do not know how unbiased it is.

I hope that this helps, but I have to go now, to level up my recently burned Mercedes to level 200 for that extra 5% EXP link-skill to give to my main. jyjy